# 2 dimensional List evaluation if than

Tags: python, list, evaluation

I generated a 2D-List. It contains filenames in one col and numbers in the second col. I now want to get a new list, containing only the filenames if the number in col 2 was >0.

However I am struggling as I have a mixed list. String & integer. And I want to read the second col to decide for the first col if I want to copy to the second list or not. How can I do this and what do I need to search for?

I tried s far len(List)  --> but did not work for the reason of the included strings

I was thinking of comparing to an array - but numpy would not like my strings and I need the strings so no way.

I tried

```
if row[1]>0:
    print (row)
```

but it did not work.

Can please anybody give me a hint what to look for?

Comment: Please show some example input and the expected output. Numpy can handle strings so your assertion is off there, but if you are new to programming then you really want to stick to Python at first anyway until you get some grounding.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this approach?

```
lst = [['file1', 1], ['file2', 0], ['file3', 7], ['file4', 0]]
new_lst = [] # a new list, containing only the filenames if the number in col 2 was >0
for row in lst:
    if row[1] > 0:
        new_lst.append(row)
```